# Passing variables between PHP pages that does not exist in the same folder

Tags: php, variables, web-deployment

I need to know how can I use a variable in script1.php in script2.php, where script2.php 's folder is included in the same folder with script1.php. Just in case there's another way, the reason I need this is to echo a user's name after he log in to his account like "Welcome $user" in script2.php where the value of $user is in script1.php .

Comment: I already solved this by using sessions ... And the answer I accepted work to just like @Rene Korss said if the script output nothing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to get your `script1.php` into `script2.php`.

**script2.php**

```
<?php
  include 'script1.php';

  // Now you can use variables from script1.php
  echo "Welcome ".$user;
?>
```

NOTE: if your `script1.php`  outputs anything, it will output its contents to `script2.php` too.

Comment: Yes!! I just tried it after posting this !! It worked .. but thx anyways :))

Comment: Okay. Please accept my answer then, since this was the solution.

Comment: Ahh !! sorry I'm new here !! I didn't know i had to do something like that =__=" .. sorry and thx

Comment: So what if my code output something? What should I do then ?

Comment: But all variables into one file, let's say `variables.php` and include it in both `script1.php` and `script2.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in session/cookie or pass the data through url
ex.

example.php?name=test&id=20

but keep in mind it depends on data you have to pass beware of url limit.